# AsyncCallback use same UI thread and Eventhandler

Tags: c#, thread-safety, eventhandler

Pls refer to below code, it's a converted program from VB to C#, and there are 2 issues I spent long time cannot solve:

1. AsyncCallback (Robot_getdata) opens a new thread. Then referencing out_text inside Robot_getdata() is giving thread reference error
2. outText.Invoke() has error "delegate event handler does not take 0 arguments"

My questions is

1. How can I make AsyncCallback (Robot_getdata) stays on same UI thread (Windows Form 1)?
2. How to fix outText.Invoke() grammer error?

// Send Data test

```
    private void Afterconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1025];
            robot_rdata = data;
            robot_callback = new AsyncCallback(Robot_getdata);
            robot_ar = Robot_socket.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, robot_callback, Robot_socket);
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect");
        }
    }

    // Get Data Test

    public void Robot_getdata(IAsyncResult ar2)
    {
        //error- reference from other thread, out_text is textbox in windows Form1
        out_text.Clear();
        try
        {
            Robot_socket = (System.Net.Sockets.Socket)ar2.AsyncState;
            Robot_socket.EndReceive(ar2);
            rdatafromem = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(robot_rdata, 0, robot_rdata.Length);

            //Below code is giving error "delegate event handler does not take 0 arguments"
            out_text.Invoke(new EventHandler(() =>
            {
                out_text.AppendText(rdatafromem + "\r\n");
            }));

            Afterconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Conenction Lost");
            login_status = false;
        }
        new_str = out_text.Text;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The async callback will happen on *whatever thread it wants*. To get back to a UI thread, use the form/control's Invoke method. Or use `async`/`await` and an awaitable API, which uses sync-context by default - which means it lands back on the UI thread in this case.